# How to define a collection in a POCO in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, collections, poco, iqueryable

Lets say I've a **Team** class which contains *0 or more* **Players**.

The **Player** class is easy:

```
public class Player
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

But whats the best to define the **Team** class?

**Option 1**

```
public class Team
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Players = new Collection<Player>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
public class Team
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

**Option 4:**

```
public class Team
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObjectSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's dispense with the unacceptable options. Option 3 isn't really right; we are in object space, not LINQ to Entities space. Option 4 isn't right, either; `ObjectSet` is for use on an `ObjectContext`, not on a POCO type.

That leaves 1 and 2. Both of them will work correctly. The Entity Framework will initialize the collection when materializing related instances from the database if you choose not to. However, option 2 does have the advantage that you can use a new `Team` in your own code before saving it to the database and reading it back. So I would probably pick that one.

Comment: Any reason not to use `Players = new List<Player>()` instead of `Players = new Collection<Player>()`?  *(Since `Collection<T>` largely a facade wrapper class around a `List<T>` but with `IsReadOnly` checks.)*

As far as Option 2, that's if you use the default parameterless constructor to create a `new Team()` without setting any properties before using it.. Then yes the collection would be initialized, but practically speaking, I can't imagine when I would do that. (Although it's one way to deal with Nullable Reference Types in C# 9.)